# When setting the object to Redux state, the key values are getting reordered

Tags: redux, react-redux

When setting the object to Redux state, the key values are getting reordered.

Input object 
{
account_id:"27523831"
bill_cycle:"7"
bill_due_date:"2015-05-31"
cost_to_serve:"3631.1"
current_balance:"1114.13"
customer_effort:"8674"
event_id:"99"
event_timestamp:"2011-07-29 23:00:00.000"
new_charges:"6095"
party_id:"1"
previous_balance:"845.11"
}

After setting Redux state
{
customer_effort: '8674'
bill_due_date: '2015-05-31'
event_id: '99'
account_id: '27523831'
party_id: '1'
bill_cycle: '7'
current_balance: '1114.13'
cost_to_serve: '3631.1'
new_charges: '6095'
event_timestamp: '2011-07-29 23:00:00.000'
previous_balance: '845.11'
}

Comment: Curious what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to rely on ordering use an `array`, `object` entries are not ordered and it might simply happen that the entry at last position is simply the last one that was updated. This behavior is normal and expected in Javascript. By definition an object in javascript: **It is an unordered collection of properties**.